# SQL Select with joins and calculate percentage

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by

I have three tables and I'm trying to make a select statement to give me a result like the one below
Teams:

```
ID   Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

Players:

```
ID   Name  TeamID
1    P1     1
2    P2     1
3    P3     2
```

Goals: (goaltype: H for home, A for away, T for training)

```
ID   PID  goaltype
1    1     A
2    1     A
3    1     H
4    2     A
5    2     H
6    3     A
7    3     T
```

Result will be Like:

```
Team    totalGoals  home    away    trainig      percentage[(home/total)*100]
A       5            2        3        0             40%  
B       2            0        1        1              0
C       0            0        0        0              0
```

This is my current query:

```
select t.name, 
  count(g.id) as totalGoals, 
  sum(case when g.GTYPE = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as home, 
  sum(case when g.GTYPE = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as away, 
  sum(case when g.GTYPE = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as training,
  --(home/totalGoals) as percentage 
from teams t 
left join players p on p.TeamID = t.id 
left join goals g on g.pid = p.id 
group by t.name
```

Comment: What sql server are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: What exactly is it you have problems with? What do you want to know? What have you tried and where are you stuck? Please show your query and tell us what the issue is you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the results you want:

```
SELECT t.Name AS Team,
       COUNT(g.goaltype) AS totalGoals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN g.goaltype = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS home,
       SUM(CASE WHEN g.goaltype = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS away,
       SUM(CASE WHEN g.goaltype = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS training,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(g.goaltype) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN g.goaltype = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
                 COUNT(g.goaltype)
       END AS percentage
FROM Teams t
LEFT JOIN Players p ON p.TeamID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN Goals g ON g.PID = p.ID
GROUP BY t.Name
ORDER BY t.Name
```

Output:

```
team    totalgoals  home    away    training    percentage
A       5           2       3       0           40
B       2           0       1       1           0
C       0           0       0       0           0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a64ba8/7)

Comment: thanks, I posted above comment and then I noticed your reply.
I stucked at the percentage, and was working on it, when I saw yours :) Thanks again

Comment: @RMohammed no worries; you do need to write the formula for `totalgoals` and `home` out again to calculate percentage as you can't use aliases in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @RMohammed I added your existing query to your question, hopefully that will prevent it getting more downvotes.

Comment: thank you so much, and accept my apology for any inconvenience